# Why was "Caribbean Blue" by Enya edited out of the Netflix release of Deadpool 2?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, music, deadpool-2

The theatrical version of *Deadpool 2* featured "Caribbean Blue", while Wade murdered people in a bath house. In the Netflix version, this is edited to be shorter, and "9 to 5" by Dolly Parton is still playing. Why?

Comment: probably something to do with rights.  I could see a meta joke somewhere though license 20 different songs and release 20 versions of the movie just to troll people.

Comment: @Revenant - More likely it's because the scene was cut right down for the Netflix edit. The theatrical was longer and so a longer song made more sense.

Comment: Maybe that song is only in the super cut, not in the theatrical version. The supercut is 15 minutes longer an therefore includes also some more songs and the bathroom scene is also longer there. So i guess netflix shows the theatrical version, and you saw the scene in the super cut version.